# How to select via jQuery an innerHTML element generated dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, innerhtml

Here is my problem.
I need to generate dynamically differents forms with a switch function.
forms are displayed step by step to present few questions with radio input with a value for the anwser.

```
function myFunctionSwitch() {
switch(myVarValue) {
case "something":
text = "<div id=\"q1\">Question
<label>Answer<input class=\"reponse\" type=\"radio\" name=\"q1\" id=\"q1r1\" value=\"462\">
<span class=\"checkmark\">
</span>
</label>
<label><input class=\"reponse\" type=\"radio\"... 
<label><input class=\"reponse\" type=\"radio\"... 
<label><input class=\"reponse\" type=\"radio\"... 
</div>"
break;
 default:...
}
document.getElementById("myModalInside").innerHTML = text;
```

I try to get input value with jQuery by this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   "use strict";
var result;
var value1;

$('#q1 .reponse').on('change', function(){  
    value1 = parseInt(this.value);
    result = value1 + ...;
});
```

This jQuery code does the right job from an html page with form write in.
But I need my switch function to present different forms.
That's why I need help.

Comment: Try creating all the forms already and hide them, show the one with matching conditions. Don't append dynamic forms from javascript. This makes life and coding easier.

Comment: Are you reading form values and submitting when form is visible or are you trying to store values in some variable and then submit all of them at the final step?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle events on a dynamically added element you need to delegate event this way:

```
$(document).on('change', '#q1 .reponse' , function() {
    value1 = parseInt(this.value);
    result = value1 + ...;
});
```

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I would suggest using the smallest possible container, which would typically be the container where the elements are dynamically added, rather than `document`. But `document` is a good failsafe if you don't know for certain where the dynamic elements will be in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help this is what I was looking for.

Comment: this question is a duplicate because of my lack of English vocabulary. I was focused on my problem and the keywords did not come to me. English is not easy to read when one is lost in codes. I'm new here, I do not know if I need to erase my question.